# Почему так сохраняется в базе?

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица `Product` с одним из столбцов `tied` предполагается, что туда будут заносится связанные товары вот таким образом установлено его заполнение в виде

```
<?php
    $product=Product::find()->where('category_id='.$cat->id)->all();
    foreach($product as $prod){ ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'tied['.$prod->title.']')->checkbox(['value' => $prod->title, 'label' => $prod->title])
    }
?>
```

вот часть экшена который отвечает за сохранение в базу

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
    foreach($post ["Product"]["tied"] as $tied){
        $model->tied .=$tied."%";
    }
    $model->save();
```

Но почему-то в базу значения не перезаписываются и добавляются. Не подскажите почему и как с этим бороться?

Comment: после `save`, если он вернет `false`, проверьте что у вас будет в `$model->getErrors()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас стоит оператор конкатенации к строке вот здесь

```
$model->tied .=$tied."%";
```

Перед тем, как записывать туда что-то - обнуляйте: `$model->tied='';`